# A more useful statusline in vim?

Tags: vim

I’d like to make my statusline in vim more informative and interesting, and for that I need some ideas. How did you customize your statusline?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for SO but might be on-topic at [Vim.SE](//vi.stackexchange.com). This question is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 135):

> Edit:-
>
> Note [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) is gaining
>   some traction as the new vimscript option as powerline has gone
>   python.

---

Seems [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) is where it is at these days:-

**Normal status line**

[image: powerline]

**Customised status lines for other plugins (e.g. [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim))**

[image: powerline]

Answer (score 63):

Here's mine:

```
set statusline=
set statusline +=%1*\ %n\ %*            "buffer number
set statusline +=%5*%{&ff}%*            "file format
set statusline +=%3*%y%*                "file type
set statusline +=%4*\ %<%F%*            "full path
set statusline +=%2*%m%*                "modified flag
set statusline +=%1*%=%5l%*             "current line
set statusline +=%2*/%L%*               "total lines
set statusline +=%1*%4v\ %*             "virtual column number
set statusline +=%2*0x%04B\ %*          "character under cursor
```

[image: vim statusline]

And here's the colors I used:

```
hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=#222222
hi User2 guifg=#dd3333 guibg=#222222
hi User3 guifg=#ff66ff guibg=#222222
hi User4 guifg=#a0ee40 guibg=#222222
hi User5 guifg=#eeee40 guibg=#222222
```

Comment: c is actually the byte count, even if it is sometimes called column count even in vim help. You can use v to get what is usually meant by column number.

Comment: Thanks @Ludwig, I haven't noticed it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I love the clarity of the commenting each appended value on it's own line. If I had done that 7 years ago, I wouldn't have thrown it out when I did my last clean OS install.

Comment: Sweeet! One thing I missing using this is the line that separates the splited session

Comment: How do you make the colors work?

Comment: I tried putting this after any `colorscheme` was set, but I just see a dual-tone  statusline.

Comment: @trusktr Note that `guifg` and `guibg` are for `gvim`. If you are running `vim` in a terminal, try `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` instead. You will also need different colors, the numbers 1-16 or 1-256 depending on how many colors you have enabled in vim. [Corresponding colors](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/vim/images/1/16/Xterm-color-table.png/revision/latest?cb=20110121055231) for each number.

Comment: where do i put these `hi User1 guifg=#eea040 guibg=#222222 .. etc` ?

Comment: @alexzander you may put them in `.gvimrc` or `.vimrc`. If you are going to set `guifg` put them in `.gvimrc` since it only applies in gvim, while `ctermfg` may be put in `.vimrc`

Comment: okey so `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` are for `vim-terminal` and in order to apply your colors i must put the color list in `.vimrc`. correct?

Comment: @alexzander yes, just replace the `gui` part of my colors with the `cterm` and place them in your .vimrc. You may also set both `gui` and `cterm` variations to your like to have both vim and gvim as you want.

Answer (score 48):

This is the one I use:

```
set statusline=
set statusline+=%7*\[%n]                                  "buffernr
set statusline+=%1*\ %<%F\                                "File+path
set statusline+=%2*\ %y\                                  "FileType
set statusline+=%3*\ %{''.(&fenc!=''?&fenc:&enc).''}      "Encoding
set statusline+=%3*\ %{(&bomb?\",BOM\":\"\")}\            "Encoding2
set statusline+=%4*\ %{&ff}\                              "FileFormat (dos/unix..) 
set statusline+=%5*\ %{&spelllang}\%{HighlightSearch()}\  "Spellanguage & Highlight on?
set statusline+=%8*\ %=\ row:%l/%L\ (%03p%%)\             "Rownumber/total (%)
set statusline+=%9*\ col:%03c\                            "Colnr
set statusline+=%0*\ \ %m%r%w\ %P\ \                      "Modified? Readonly? Top/bot.
```

Highlight on? function:

```
function! HighlightSearch()
  if &hls
    return 'H'
  else
    return ''
  endif
endfunction
```

Colors (adapted from ligh2011.vim):

```
hi User1 guifg=#ffdad8  guibg=#880c0e
hi User2 guifg=#000000  guibg=#F4905C
hi User3 guifg=#292b00  guibg=#f4f597
hi User4 guifg=#112605  guibg=#aefe7B
hi User5 guifg=#051d00  guibg=#7dcc7d
hi User7 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#880c0e gui=bold
hi User8 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#5b7fbb
hi User9 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#810085
hi User0 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#094afe
```

[image: My StatusLine]

Comment: Nice, this avoids the need to have the fancy status line plugins atleast for my use case, eye candy :)

Comment: How do you get the colors to work?

Comment: I tried putting this after any `colorscheme` was set, but I just see a dual-tone  statusline.

Comment: @trusktr, Not easy to explain....You need the put the first 2 blocks in your vimrc file and the colors block in your current colorscheme file. You can find your current colorscheme file with this command: `:colorscheme`

Comment: @Reman I can't just stick those colors in my vimrc? I do have other colors in my vimrc that work.

Comment: @trusktr, you just have to add above colors at the end of your colorscheme file.

Comment: @Reman But why is it that I cannot stick these colors in my vimrc after my `colorscheme` command?

Comment: @trusktr I don't know why it doesn't work in your case

Comment: @trusktr you could use `augroup stl | autocmd ! | autocmd ColorScheme * call LoadStatusLineColors | augroup END` then make a `function LoadStatusLineColors | hi User1 guifg=banana guibg=platypus | hi User2 ... | ... | endfunction` (where `|` is a newline in both snippets. I am assuming that you colorscheme is somehow overridding your statusline `hi`s, so doing what I just showed you will override your colorscheme *every time* it is loaded. :)

Comment: Your highlight search would be shorter (without any function) just by using ternary operator like this -> `echo &hls ? 'H' : ''`  in my case: `let &stl.="%6*%01(%{&hls?'H':''}%)%0* "`

Comment: For me, it didn't work because I'm using a terminal, so apparently instead of guifg=hexnumber, I have to set ctermfg and ctermbg and use a named color (Blue, Magenta, Green, etc.)

Answer (score 20):

What I've found useful is to know which copy/paste buffer (register) is currently active: `%{v:register}`. Otherwise, my complete status line looks almost exactly like the standard line.

```
:set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r\ %y%=%{v:register}\ %-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

Answer (score 17):

Some times less is more, do you really need to know the percentage through the file you are when coding? What about the type of file?

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ 
set statusline+=%{fugitive#statusline()}\    
set statusline+=[%{strlen(&fenc)?&fenc:&enc}]
set statusline+=\ [line\ %l\/%L]          
set statusline+=%{rvm#statusline()}
```

[image: statusline]

[image: statusline]

I also prefer minimal color as not to distract from the code.

Taken from: https://github.com/krisleech/vimfiles

Note: `rvm#statusline` is Ruby specific and `fugitive#statusline` is git specific.

Answer (score 6):

I currently use this statusbar settings:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=\ %f%m%r%h%w\ %=%({%{&ff}\|%{(&fenc==\"\"?&enc:&fenc).((exists(\"+bomb\")\ &&\ &bomb)?\",B\":\"\")}%k\|%Y}%)\ %([%l,%v][%p%%]\ %)
```

My complete .vimrc file:
http://gabriev82.altervista.org/projects/vim-configuration/

Answer (score 4):

`set statusline=%<%f%m\ \[%{&ff}:%{&fenc}:%Y]\ %{getcwd()}\ \ \[%{strftime('%Y/%b/%d\ %a\ %I:%M\ %p')}\]\ %=\ Line:%l\/%L\ Column:%c%V\ %P`

This is mine, give as a suggestion