# Change vim's linestatus colors

Tags: configuration, vim

I have successfully set my `linestatus` configuration. However, the only thing missing is some background color, either for the *whole line* as well as in *particular elements*. How can I set them?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim/5380230#5380230) for an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the colours as new highlighting groups User1, User2, etc:

```
hi User1 ctermbg=blue    ctermfg=white   guibg=blue    guifg=white
hi User2 ctermbg=black   ctermfg=red     guibg=black   guifg=red
```

Then you can specify them in the statusline string like so:

```
set statusline=
set statusline+=%1*   " Switch to colour User1
set statusline+=%F
set statusline+=%*    " Switch to default colour
set statusline+=%P
set statusline+=%2*   " Switch to colour User2
set statusline+=%c
```

**EDIT**

This probably belongs in a new question, but here is the method I use to find the existing colouring for a highlight group. In this example I set the `Folded` syntax to be the same as the current `Normal` syntax. I do this by directing the output of `hi Normal` to a variable, and then extracting the various information from it.

```
redir => hinorm
sil exe 'hi Normal'
redir END
if hinorm =~ 'cleared'
    sil exe 'hi clear Folded'
else
    let guibg = matchstr(strtrans(hinorm),'guibg=[#a-zA-Z0-9]*')
    let guifg = matchstr(strtrans(hinorm),'guifg=[#a-zA-Z0-9]*')
    sil exe 'hi Folded ' . guibg
    sil exe 'hi Folded ' . guifg
endif
```

If there is a cleaner method, let me know!

Comment: by any change did you manage to find a way of knowing the colors Solarized or any other scheme is using, so I could its default fg and bg colors in an automated way?

Comment: It probably belongs in a new question, but I have added my method for finding the current fg/bg colours. Hope it helps.