# How to write vimrc to show time and git info on vim's ruler bar

Tags: vim

In vim 7.3, I'd like to show the current time and git info on the ruler bar.

How can I do this?

From vim's guide, it seems I should modify the rulerformat option, but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. for git info, better way to do it is using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), after you installed the fugitive vim plugin, you can set your statusline in your .vimrc

   set statusline =... %{fugitive#statusline()} ...
2. to display time in your statusline, you need `strftime` function, eg.

   set statusline+=%{strftime("%I:%M")}

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim) for more statusline ideas