# How do I make vim statusline like this

Tags: vim

I have several screenshots of vim where the status line looks like this (specifically the triangle like backgrounds)

[image: statusline example]

The original [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8848009/1233517) claims this as the default.

However my vim status line looks like this by default (i have changed only the colorscheem to Tomorrow-Night)

[image]

How do I make my status line look more like the above.

I am using vim-gnome on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The original post claims this as the default considering you installed `powerline` plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go:

https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline

It is a nice plugin. personally I tried and don't like this plugin... :(

even though vim questions are welcomed to SO, this one may go to superuser or some other channel....

Comment: Oops.. just did a search in github, copied the wrong url... answer updated to the right one.

Comment: It is not wrong: defaults from the screenshot are `vim-powerline` ones (in new powerline there would be pale `./` before file name, `+` colored by yellow, `NORMAL` in place of `N` and red (really gradient, but 100% is red) relative line position; everything may be adjusted to make powerlines indistinguashable, but that won’t be the defaults). It does not mean though that it is not deprecated; there are some known issues in `vim-powerline` that are not going to be ever fixed.