# Vim - count nonblank nonwhitespace lines

Tags: vim

Using GVIM, I'd like to have something similar to the line count MSExcel offers - an on-the-fly line count that shows me how many lines I've selected so far that are non-blank (i.e. don't contain only whitespaces).

Up until now I've always used `y` for yank and then it shows on the bottom how many lines yanked, but:

1. this is not on-the-fly
2. this counts also blank/whitespace lines.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim

Answer (score 4):

The downside of `:substitute//n` is that is clobbers the last search pattern and search history, and its output contains additional text and is difficult to capture. Alternatively, you can `filter()` the entire buffer, and count the matches:

```
:echo len(filter(getline(1, '$'), 'v:val =~# "\\S"'))
```

This can be easily turned into a custom mapping or command. If the performance is acceptable, you can even add this to your `'statusline'`:

```
:let &statusline .= ' %{len(filter(getline(1, "$"), ''v:val =~# "\\S"''))} lines'
```

Note: The statusline update won't work during a visual selection, because the marks `'<` and `'>` are only set after you've *left* the selection.

Comment: The question asks about selected lines, not all lines in the buffer.  You can get a little closer by using `getline("'<", "'>")` instead of `getline(1, "$")`.  (Remember to use `''` to get `'` inside a literal string.)  Unfortunately, the status line does not update while in Visual mode. :-(  Also, if you do not see the status line at all, check the `'laststatus'` option.

Comment: @benjifisher: Thanks, I missed that. The problem with the statusline is that the marks are only set _after_ the selection; added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\S//n
3 matches on 3 lines
```

This combines a no-op `:substitute` (with the `/n` flag) that only counts the matching lines with the `\S` atom, which matches non-whitespace. As long as there is any such in a line, it is counted.

For the visual selection, just trigger it from there; it'll automatically use `:'<,'>` range instead of `:%`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of blank lines you could use

```
:%s/^.\+//n
```

of course, instead of `%` you can use any other range command.
However, this approach will count only non-blank lines (without whitespace) not starting with a whitespace. Some hints on counting search results can be found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern).

To allow for whitespace recognition you could use something like

```
:%s/^.*[^ ]\+//n
```