# Full list of variables that can be used in a vim statusline

Tags: vim

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim) question - I was wondering if there was a list of all the variables that you can use in the status line in vim - e.g `%F` seems to be full file path and `%L` seems to be 'total number of lines - would anyone have a link to a comprehensive listing of all of the magic variables?

Comment: `:help statusline`, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information can be found under `:help 'statusline'`; all options are single-quoted in the Vim help. There's a link from `:help status-line`, too.

Learn how the excellent and comprehensive `:help` is structured; all the information is in there (you just need to know how to find it)!

Additionally, with the `%{...}` syntax, you can include arbitrary Vimscript expressions in the statusline as well, so you have all the flexibility you need. Plugins like [airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) showcase what is possible there; it might be worth exploring plugins like those before rolling your own.

Comment: I'd suggest the opposite: play with `statusline` before installing a fancy *line plugin.