# Can I somehow add my own info to the status line via vimscript

Tags: vim

Can I somehow add my own info to the status line via vimscript? I need to create plugin that will update some value in the status line after certain time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'statusline'` option configures what is shown in the status line. You can add the value of arbitrary Vimscript expressions via the `%{expr}` syntax, e.g.:

```
:set statusline+=\ %{localtime()}
```

Note that this gets invoked frequently, so it shouldn't do much processing. Alternatively, just insert a (buffer-local) variable, and use other means (`:autocmd`) to update the variable value when necessary.

If you plan to make this plugin reusable, better not directly mess with the `'statusline'` option, but just offer a (global or autoload) function and instructions for users to include this in their personal option value.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can update the value of `&statusline`, by putting your new stuff in.

e.g.

```
let &statusline .= "Hello"
```

this will add a `Hello` to the end of statusline.