# How to add a variable amount of characters to a vim statusline based on available whitespace in the statusline

Tags: vim, statusline

I have made my custom status line for vim and I ran into a problem, When I do :split, it becomes very hard to see the separation between the buffers because of the way I set it up. I now want to add a character to act as a separating border between the text on the left side to the right side. On the left, I have a file name and its path(Which alters in length), on the right I have some information about the buffer number and such. I cannot hard code a character because sometime when the file path is too long it gets cut off. I want to be able to call a function that will return a variable amount of a character based on the amount of white space I have between the two ends of the status line.

I have thought of multiple ways to solve this but I just do not know how to do it and I cannot find answers online.
At first, I had an idea of just underlining the whole status line but I do not know how to do this.

Now my idea for adding a variable number of characters is a different, I want to define a function that uses regex to read the status line text and replace the line with a variable amount of characters that would fit perfectly in the given whitespace.

I do not know how to do this and I would appreciate any help.
In addition, I also wanted to make a certain element of the status bar change color based on which buffer my cursor is in so it is easier to find the correct window, I could not find a way to do this either and a pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%2*\ %l
set statusline+=\ %*
set statusline+=%1*\ ‹‹
set statusline+=%1*\ %t\ %*
set statusline+=%1*\ ››
set statusline+=%1*\ %m
set statusline+=%3*\ %F
set statusline+=%{AddSeperator()}
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%3*\ ‹‹
set statusline+=%3*\ %{strftime('%R',getftime(expand('%')))}
set statusline+=%3*\ ::
set statusline+=%3*\ %n
set statusline+=%3*\ ››\ %*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just do not know how to do it and I cannot find answers online

The best place to look for answers is Vim's help system. In this case it's `:help 'statusline'`. After finishing it, you may simply google for other people's work to learn by example. [A relevant topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375240/a-more-useful-statusline-in-vim), [an inspirational vimrc](https://dustri.org/pub/vimrc). And, of course ;-), here is [my status line](https://github.com/matveyt/vimfiles/blob/master/autoload/statusline.vim).

> I cannot hard code a character because sometime when the file path is too long it gets cut off.

That means you have to cut a file path instead. Then you can add a single space to make sure there's at least one:

```
set statusline+=%3*\ %<%F
set statusline+=\ %=
```

If you don't like "plain spaces", read `:help 'fillchars'`.

> I also wanted to make a certain element of the status bar change color based on which buffer my cursor is in so it is easier to find the correct window

Just use the default color (`%*`) for some element and it will switch between `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` automatically. The same way as it is for the default status line. If you don't like `StatusLine` in your current colorscheme, you can forcefully change it with `:highlight` command. But note that `StatusLine` is also used for `WildMenu`.

> At first, I had an idea of just underlining the whole status line but I do not know how to do this.

You don't underline "some text" in Vim. You use "underlined" color groups instead. Sort of `:hi User1 gui=underline guifg=... guibg=...` etc.

Comment: Hello, I found everything very helpful. I wanted to ask you for guidance with the underline part, I really like the look of it but since each element has a different color so does the underline per element and I was wondering if I could create a “parent” highlight group that the entire status bar inherits hence giving me a single color underline for the whole thing.

Comment: @ItayBachar It does not work this way. Underline is always drawn in current text color (guifg). Only undercurl and strikethrough can make use of a different color (guisp). See `:help :highlight`.